# How do I use HTTP/2 for manifest.json?

Tags: angular, progressive-web-apps

I ran the Lighthouse extension on my angular PWA. The only error I am getting is as follows?

Does not use HTTP/2 for all of its resources
1 request not served via HTTP/2

[image: Lighthouse error]

What steps do I need to take to remedy this?

Comment: `HTTP/2` needs to be enabled from your hosting server settings like Nginx,  Apache, etc.

Comment: My hosting is on a shared server. It is weird to me that the manifest.json is the only file that gets that error.

Comment: Agreed. It quite strange to get that error only for a single file. Can you share the network request made for the manifest file.

Comment: It is being served by the service worker.

Comment: You mean the service worker cache ?

Comment: For me it's showing `h/2`. There was a bug in DevTools that incorrectly showed assets served via service worker as always being `http/1.1` so I think you site is fine.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Its a tad frustrating because my lighthouse best practices score is 93 and that manifest.json using protocol http/1.1 is the only issue keeping it from getting 100.